# Seeking Python library (other than ArcPy) for geoprocessing such as buffer?

Tags: python, buffer, software-recommendations

Excluding ArcPy, is there any python library which can do geoprocessing, such as buffer/intersect, with shapefiles?

Answer (score 17):

The **[Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#buffer-a-geometry)** has some sample code to **Buffer a Geometry**.

```
from osgeo import ogr

wkt = "POINT (1198054.34 648493.09)"
pt = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)
bufferDistance = 500
poly = pt.Buffer(bufferDistance)
print "%s buffered by %d is %s" % (pt.ExportToWkt(), bufferDistance, poly.ExportToWkt())
```

and to **[Calculate intersection between two Geometries](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#calculate-intersection-between-two-geometries)**

```
from osgeo import ogr

wkt1 = "POLYGON ((1208064.271243039 624154.6783778917, 1208064.271243039 601260.9785661874, 1231345.9998651114 601260.9785661874, 1231345.9998651114 624154.6783778917, 1208064.271243039 624154.6783778917))"
wkt2 = "POLYGON ((1199915.6662253144 633079.3410163528, 1199915.6662253144 614453.958118695, 1219317.1067437078 614453.958118695, 1219317.1067437078 633079.3410163528, 1199915.6662253144 633079.3410163528)))"

poly1 = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt1)
poly2 = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt2)

intersection = poly1.Intersection(poly2)

print intersection.ExportToWkt()
```

The geometries can be read and written to **shapefiles** and a variety of other formats.

Answer (score 14):

To simplify, [Shapely: manual](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)  allows all geometry processing of PostGIS in Python.

> The first premise of Shapely is that Python programmers should be able to perform PostGIS type geometry operations outside of an RDBMS...

The first example of PolyGeo

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon, mapping
from shapely.wkt import loads  
pt = Point(1198054.34,648493.09)
# or
pt = loads("POINT (1198054.34 648493.09)")
bufferDistance = 500
poly = pt.buffer(bufferDistance)
print poly.wkt
'POLYGON ((1198554.3400000001000000 648493.0899999999700000, 1198551.9323633362000000 
# GeoJSON
print mapping(poly)
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((1198554.34, 648493.09), (1198551.9323633362, 648444.0814298352), (1198544.7326402017, 648395.544838992), ....}
```

The polygon's example from PolyGeo:

```
poly1 = Polygon([(1208064.271243039,624154.6783778917), (1208064.271243039,601260.9785661874), (1231345.9998651114,601260.9785661874),(1231345.9998651114,624154.6783778917),(1208064.271243039,624154.6783778917)])    
poly2 = loads("POLYGON ((1199915.6662253144 633079.3410163528, 1199915.6662253144 614453.958118695, 1219317.1067437078 614453.958118695, 1219317.1067437078 633079.3410163528, 1199915.6662253144 633079.3410163528)))"

intersection = poly1.intersection(poly2)
print intersection.wkt
print mapping(intersection) -> GeoJSON
```

> The second premise is that the persistence, serialization, and map projection of features are significant, but orthogonal problems. You may not need a hundred GIS format readers and writers or the multitude of State Plane projections, and Shapely doesn’t burden you with them.

So you combine it with other Python modules to read or write shapefiles and manipulate projections as osgeo.ogr,  [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) or [PyShp](http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/).
Searching in Gis StackExchange, you can find many examples but I give you another one to illustrate the  combination of shapely and Fiona and the use of the shapely functions intersection() and buffer() (This could have been done with PyShp).

Given two polyline shapefiles:

[image]

Compute the intersection (function intersection() of shapely)

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPolygon, MumtiPoint, MultiLineString,shape, mapping
import fiona
# read the shapefiles and transform to MultilineString shapely geometry (shape())
layer1 = MultiLineString([shape(line['geometry']) for line in fiona.open('polyline1.shp')])  
layer2 = MultiLineString([shape(line['geometry']) for line in fiona.open('polyline2.shp')])
points_intersect = layer1.intersection(layer2)
```

Save the result as a new shapefile

```
# schema of the new shapefile
schema = {'geometry': 'MultiPoint','properties': {'test': 'int'}}
# write the new shapefile (function mapping() of shapely)
with fiona.open('intersect.shp','w','ESRI Shapefile', schema) as e:
  e.write({'geometry':mapping(points_intersect), 'properties':{'test':1}})
```

Result:

[image]

Buffer individual points (function buffer() of shapely)

```
 # new schema
 schema = {'geometry': 'Polygon','properties': {'test': 'int'}}
 with fiona.open('buffer.shp','w','ESRI Shapefile', schema) as e:
     for point in points:
          e.write({'geometry':mapping(point.buffer(300)), 'properties':{'test':1}})
```

Result

[image]

Buffer the MultiPoint geometry

```
schema = {'geometry': 'MultiPolygon','properties': {'test': 'int'}}
points.buffer(300)
with fiona.open('buffer2.shp','w','ESRI Shapefile', schema) as e:
     e.write({'geometry':mapping(points.buffer(300)), 'properties':{'test':1}})
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) gives python access to [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) which can do buffers/intersects/etc.  GEOS is the library most OSGeo programs use to perform those operations.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my list of Python geoprocessing software.

- Shapely, python
- OGR, python
- QGIS, pyqgis, python
- SagaGIS, python
- Grass, python
- spatialite, pyspatialite, python
- PostreSQL/PostGIS, Psycopg, python
- R Project, rpy2, python
- Whitebox GAT, python
  -GeoScript, jython

Answer (score 1):

My 'go to' geo-processing library is the 'Remote Sensing and GIS Library' (RSGISLib). Its easy to install and use and the documentation is really good. It has functionality for vector and raster processing - I very rarely have to go near a gui. It can be found here: http://rsgislib.org.

An example in this instance is:

```
rsgislib.vectorutils.buffervector(inputvector, outputvector, bufferDist, force)
```

A command to buffer a vector by a specified distance.

Where:

- inputvector is a string containing the name of the input vector
- outputvector is a string containing the name of the output vector
- bufferDist is a float specifying the distance of the buffer, in map units
- force is a bool, specifying whether to force removal of the output vector if it exists

Example:

```
from rsgislib import vectorutils
inputVector = './Vectors/injune_p142_stem_locations.shp'
outputVector = './TestOutputs/injune_p142_stem_locations_1mbuffer.shp'
bufferDist = 1
vectorutils.buffervector(inputVector, outputVector, bufferDist, True)
```